# For a 16-bit integer variable, can you assign the variable with an integer value of 72368?

Tags: c, integer

Could you please give a thorough explanation of this ?

Comment: The compiler will truncate the value so it fits, but that stored value will not be 72368.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try, but if the assignment succeeds it will not store the entirety of your original number, because representing it with accuracy requires more than 16 bits.

The highest order bit in a 16 bit integer is the 2<sup>15</sup> place. Two to the fifteenth power is 32768.  Setting your 16 bits to all ones will yield 65535 (32768 * 2 - 1), if the integer is unsigned, so that's the highest number you can assign reliably.

In any case, this is easy enough to test:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  unsigned short i = 72368;
  printf("%d\n", i); // 6832
  return 0;
}
```

Note that 72368 is interpreted as an `int`, and an implicit conversion occurs to `unsigned short`, although the compiler will warn you. [Try it online](https://replit.com/@robertwharvey/ComfortableDevotedTranslation#main.c).

Comment: Thank you :) for helping. 
I have tried it online too. it works, and your explantion is clear to me.

Comment: Better to use `uint16_t` here?

Comment: @klutt: It's just illustrative code, not production code, and I would imagine you'd have the same problem with `uint16_t`.

Comment: Yes I understood it's just illustrative. But I still think it's better since 1) unsigned short has a minimum width but not exakt width and 2) it would make your example very much clearer. But I don't know. Just a thought.

Answer (score -2):

No, because the maximum value you can encode in 16 bits is 65535